# Is there any way to not attack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-puzzle-quest

This may seem counter-intuitive to winning, but some of the challenges tend to require a great deal of luck in order to obtain crystal rewards. I'm currently bashing my head against "Win the fight with 9 or less HP remaining" against a Hangarback Walker. Annoyingly, I *had* this challenge in the bag by accident the first time, and then a runaway series of combos managed to trigger a healing spell, and, well...

If the CPU gets a good hand and favorable board layouts, it tends to snowball. If it doesn't, it tends to flail helplessly. So setting up a situation where I can still win with low health is iffy.

In my last attempt I managed to get it into a good spot, but the CPU needed one more turn to bring me under 9 - a turn it would not have because there did not seem to be any way to prevent my creatures from attacking and defeating the enemy (who was at 1 HP).

So is there any way to prevent my side attacking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not in the current release of the game.

I've shot my own creatures with Chandra's middle ability to meet certain challenges...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always use one of the Planewalkers that can hurt the opponent without monsters, like Chandra or Ob Nixius, and fill up your card inventory with spells and the like that can take out the opponent's units until they become spell-swamped. After that, it's just a delay game. And if you run into a creature you don't want out yet, you can always discard the card.